# Como hacer Repetir eventos en fullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

como puedo repetir eventos en FullCalendar por ejemplo: 2018-1-1 y repetirlo en 4 dias 2018-1-5 y que se muestre los dos eventos (2018-1-1 y el otro evento 2018-1-5) en el calendar.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que usar la opción dow de la siguiente manera:

```
events: [{
    title:"Repeticion evento",
    start: '10:00',
    end: '14:00',        
    dow: [ 1, 4 ] // Repetir Lunes y Jueves
}],
```

[Aqui](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/businessHours/) se muestra la documentación, te deje un [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Rastalovely/vmb22a59/):

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta pero No me funciona, no tienes otra forma? sabes como puedo hacerlo atraves del php donde se envian los datos a la bd? con un bucle FOR algo asi, que si pongo que se repita 4 veces se muestre en la bd 4 veces pero con fechas diferentes

Comment: @ArnelCariagaJr. la solución que da Rastalovely va bien y hace lo que pides en la pregunta, ¿cómo no te funciona? ¿recibes algún error? Lo que pides de PHP/BD realmente no está relacionado con la pregunta original, para eso deberías hacer una pregunta nueva.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Rastalovely ya me funciona.